# How to solve this counting problem relating to function mapping?

Tags: combinatorics

How many functions are there from the set {1,2,...,n}, where n is a positive integer, to the set {0,1} that assign 1 to exactly one of the positive integers less than n?

The answer from my textbook is 2(n-1), but I can't fathom out the logic behind the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $ n - 1 $ numbers less then $ n $ in $ \{1, 2, ..., n\} $, define the function $$ f_{i, 0} :  \{1, 2, ..., n\}  \rightarrow \{0 ,1\}  $$ such that 
$f_{i, 0}(n) = 0 $,  $ f_{i, 0}(x) = 1 \text{ if x = i } $ and $ f_{i, 0}(x) = 0$ otherwise, for $ i=1, 2, ..., n-1 $

There are clearly $ n -1 $ functions like this; furthermore there are another $ n-1 $ functions 
$$ f_{i, 1} :  \{1, 2, ..., n\}  \rightarrow \{0 ,1\}  $$
such that $f_{i, 1}(n) = 1 $,  $ f_{i, 1}(x) = 1 \text{ if x = i } $ and $ f_{i, 1}(x) = 0$ otherwise, for $ i=1, 2, ..., n-1 $.

Therefore you have a total of $2(n-1)$ functions with the desire properties.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : choose the value for $f(n)$ (no condition for this) then choose the unique integer $i$, $1\leq i\leq n-1$ for which $f(i)=1$ then the others will be sent to $0$.